# Register live range

Tags: compiler-construction

I am a studying compilers liveness and live ranges but a little bit confused. The figure below taken from tutorial and shows a live ranges for a given code. For example it says that `R2` is loaded at line 2 `load r2, 2` and its value is valid until line 6 `mult r1, r1, r2`. Why? At line 6 we performing multiplication and assign results back to `R1` but not in `R2`, then why `R2` looses its value?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it's not so much that the value in `R2` is invalidated at step 6, but that it's no longer needed in this function as none of the later instructions reference it, so it can be considered dead. Alive/dead is not the same thing as valid/invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of live ranges is to find out how to minimize the usage of registers. In order to do that, we need to find out how long does a value in a register have to be kept, because it will be needed in later calculations.

As twalberg said, `r2` is no longer needed and so we could potentially use this register to store a different value.